# Show that the addition function, $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow R$, given by $f(x,y)=x+y$ is a continuous function.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Show that the addition function, $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow R$, given by $f(x,y)=x+y$ is a continuous function

If someone can give me a most clean proof this was very nice.
Thanks for read my proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lvert f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) \rvert = \lvert x + y  - x_0 - y_0 \rvert = \lvert x - x_0  + y - y_0 \rvert \le \lvert x - x_0  \rvert + \lvert y - y_0 \rvert  \\ = \lVert (x,y) - (x_0,y_0) \rVert_1 .$$
Here $\lVert (a,b) \rVert_1 = \lvert a  \rvert + \lvert b \rvert_1$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^2$ which induces the usual topology on $\mathbb  R^2$ (i.e. the product topology on $\mathbb  R \times \mathbb  R$). This norm is equivalent to the Euclidean norm $\lVert (a,b) \rVert_2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ since $\lVert (a,b) \rVert_2 \le \lVert (a,b) \rVert_1$ and $\lVert (a,b) \rVert_1 \le 2\lVert (a,b) \rVert_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=(a,b)$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R},a<b$ a open in $R$ we should prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.\
Consider $f^{-1}(a,b)= \lbrace (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:a<x+y<b\rbrace$ and notice that these region is a subset in the plane between $y=b-x$ and $y=a-x$,Namely $L$.
Let Fix $P=(x,y)\in L$ chose $\varepsilon>0$ such that $$a+\varepsilon<x+y<b-\varepsilon$$
and consider $B_{\epsilon/2}(P)$.Pick $Q\in B_{\varepsilon/2}(P)$we will prove that $Q \in L $ ie($a<q_1+q_2<b)$ by definition $$\sqrt{(q_1-x)^2+(q_2-y)^2}<\varepsilon/2$$
$$|q_1-x|<\varepsilon/2$$
$$|q_2-y|<\varepsilon/2$$
$$|q_1-x|+|q_2-y|<\varepsilon$$
$$|q_1+q_2-(x+y)|<|q_1-x|+|q_2-y|<\varepsilon$$
$$|q_1+q_2-(x+y)|<\varepsilon$$
$$-\varepsilon+(x+y)<q_1+q_2< \varepsilon+(x+y)$$
by our election of $\varepsilon$ we get
$$-\varepsilon+a+\varepsilon<q_1+q_2< \varepsilon+b-\varepsilon$$
$$a<q_1+q_2<b$$ therefore $Q\in L$ and $L=f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, Hence $f$ is a continuous function since $P$ was arbitrary in $f^{-1}(U)$.